# How to fill percentage of an image's background with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I have an image of a male body and as you can see below I want to fill inside of the Image with blue when people click Drink button. For example when you click first time it will fill inside with %20. But I couldn't find how to achieve this. If you need more information about image please tell because I don't know it may related with image itself.

Update : I downloaded this image not like a rectangle image. It is in PNG format and it has only lines as I know. If there is a solution to make an image only contains lines you can specify also.

```
@Composable
fun WaterTracing() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.male),
            contentDescription = "A man illustration",
            Modifier.size(500.dp))

        Button(onClick = {

        }) {
            Text(text = "DRINK WATER")
        }



    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's anything built into Kotlin or Compose that'll do that for you. You'll need an image manipulation library.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to use image masking on a bitmap:
https://medium.com/bumble-tech/masking-bitmaps-628ac883e17d

Comment: As a developer sometimes you have to think smart and out of the box. You can have a PNG image with light gray background on top and cut only the inside of the human. Then you put a vertical progress bar behind and boom. You can have all shorts of animation and anything you can imagine simply ;)

Comment: Do you have filled version of that PNG file. Because what you need is actually the filled version to apply BlendMode as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73996333/5457853), then you can draw outlined version above filled version and a rectangle with BlendMode

Comment: I tried to implement this stackoverflow answer to my problem but couldn't achieve. It makes automatically 5 items and filling from left to right but I need vertical version of this. I am trying to implement. If you are able to do this can you provide me some code ?