# How to draw an intersection of circles in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, canvas, graphics, android-jetpack-compose, compose-multiplatform

I'm trying to draw an intersection of 2 circles using `BlendMode.DstIn`  on the second one to mask the first one, but the result shows only the first circle without any modifications.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun BlendModeTest() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .graphicsLayer(alpha = 0.99f, compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen)
    ) {
        drawCircle(Color.Cyan, 300f, Offset(500f, 500f))
        drawCircle(Color.Black, 300f, Offset(700f, 500f), blendMode = BlendMode.DstIn)
    }
}
```

Expected result: [image: like a lens]

Actual: [image: only 1st circle]

What am I doing wrong, am I supposed to use different `BlendMode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying BlendMode to black circle. The most it can interact with cyan circle is intersection but left section of cyan circle will remain present because no blend mode is applied to that section.

Check link below. When blend mode is applied to source image which covers other image depending on which blendmode it is is applied to every pixel.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode

You can use paths with `PathOperation.Intersection` to have desired outcome.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun IntersectionTest() {
    
    val path = remember {
        Path()
    }

    
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        if (path.isEmpty) {


            val tempPath1 = Path().apply {
                addOval(
                    Rect(
                        radius = 300f,
                        center = Offset(500f, 500f)
                    )
                )
            }

            val tempPath2 = Path().apply {
                addOval(
                    Rect(
                        radius = 300f,
                        center = Offset(700f, 500f)
                    )
                )
            }

            val diffPath = Path.combine(
                operation = PathOperation.Intersect,
                path1 = tempPath1,
                path2 = tempPath2
            )

            path.addPath(diffPath)

        }

        drawPath(path, color = Color.Cyan)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But i'm still confused as to why what i tried didn't. I tried replacing `drawCircle`'s with `drawImage(<bitmap of a circle>, ...)` just to check and it worked. So as i understand, `BlendMode` works fully only when source and destination are different bitmaps/layers, right?

Comment: If the drawing covers first one you can still apply it as desired. For example if you draw a circle without blend mode and a rectangle with blend mode that covers that circle you can apply blend modes as in examples. In your question you are never applying blend mode to right section of cyan circle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73996333/5457853 Check this rating bar answer. Rectangle covers star images and because of that you can apply blend modes to star images