# Compose Icon tint is not applied for Icon that have two default colors like Icons.Rounded.StarHalf

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to apply a custom tint color according to the current theme weather it's dark or light, it works fine for most of the icons but when i try to apply it for StarHalf, it's not applied.

```
Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Rounded.StarHalf,
        contentDescription = null,
        tint = iconTintColor,
        modifier = Modifier
            .selectable(
                indication = if (isIndicator) LocalIndication.current else null,
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                selected = isSelected,
            )
            .width(starSize)
            .height(starSize)
    )
```

also tried to use Image but it doesn't work!

```
Image(
        imageVector = Icons.Rounded.StarHalf,
        contentDescription = null,
        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(iconTintColor),
        modifier = Modifier
            .selectable(
                indication = if (isIndicator) LocalIndication.current else null,
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                selected = isSelected,
            )
            .width(starSize)
            .height(starSize)
    )
```

Any idea how to force the color of the transparent part of the star ?
This is the preview :

### [image: The preview]

Comment: You need to use ```Canvas``` and draw custom Star shape and. the apply the Colors.

Comment: You can apply blend mode in Canvas or with draw modifiers. You can refer this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73996333/5457853